# How does a document-based database and CouchDB in particular handle ID references?

Tags: reference, couchdb, document-based

I really like the document-based approach of storing data like blog posts as a whole document with all information needed saved inside of it. Therefore the author´s username is stored as plain text. The author himself has his own document with personal information attached to it. What happens when the author decides to change his username? Do I have to update every document the contains a blog post by that author or is this just one of the drawbacks using a document-based database?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to write a query(view) with content from the blogpost and the name of the author, then the name must be included in the blog content, and therefore **all blogposts must be updated.**

if the name is only for information ( i mean you do not query a blogpost-content like keywords AND name of author), you can add the id into the blog document (and of course now can Query blog content AND author-id) and emit {'_id':doc.author_id} as a Value.
`include_docs=true` then gives you the doc of the Author (and no longer the blogpost-doc.. you have to call it explicit with the id thats in the result rows). **No Need to update the blogposts.**

Example:
**Case 1:** 
Use Author by Name, you have to include the name, and therefore update ALL docs.

```
{
 "_id":"blogpost1",
 "author":"Oliver",
 "keyword":"couchDB"
}
```

to look for all couchdb posts from oliver:

```
emit ([doc.author,doc.keyword],1)
```

call:

```
&key=["Oliver","couchDB"]
```

**Case 2:** 
No need to query by name

```
    {
     "_id":"blogpost1",
     "author_id":"author-123",
     "keyword":"couchDB"
    }

   emit (doc.keyword,{'_id':doc.author_id})
```

and the authors doc:

```
{
"_id":"author-123",
"name":"Oliver"
}
```

call:

```
?key=["couchDB"]&include_docs=true
```

result:

```
...
{"id":"blogpost1","key":"couchDB","value":{"_id":"author-123"},"doc":{"_id":"author-123","_rev":"xxx","name":"Oliver,....
```

Comment: Thanks okurow, for your response. I thought about it in theory and did not know how that will work. Then I tried it at home and it did not work. I followed every of your steps. But when I call my view it does not append the author´s document but the blog´s document to the output.

Comment: Check it out at : http://thinkcouchdb.iriscouch.com/includedocs/_design/queries/_view/byKeyword?key=%22couchDB%22&include_docs=true .. feel free to look at the example Database "includedocs"
Thanks, iriscouch.com for the free hosting.

Comment: Thanks again okurow! You were right. I also just read about it in the official wiki.